# Support for Cordformation plugin in Corda 5 Developer Preview release

Tags: corda

I am trying to modify my simple Cordapp developed for Corda 4.8 to work on Corda 5 developer preview release. We are using Cordformation plugin to define Corda network through our build.gradle file like below:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    nodeDefaults {
        projectCordapp {
            deploy = false
        }
        cordapp project(':contracts')
        cordapp project(':workflows')
        runSchemaMigration = false
    }
    node {
        name "O=Notary, L=London, C=UK"
        notary = [validating : false]
        p2pPort 23001
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:23002")         
            adminAddress("localhost:13042")
        }
        sshdPort 17741
        cordapp (project(':workflows'))
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyA, L=London, C=UK"
        notary = [validating : false, serviceLegalName : "O=Notary, L=London, C=UK"]
        p2pPort 23003
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:23004")
            adminAddress("localhost:13044")
        }
        sshdPort 17742
        cordapp (project(':workflows'))
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyB, L=London, C=UK"
        notary = [validating : false, serviceLegalName : "O=Notary, L=London, C=UK"]
        p2pPort 23005
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:23006")
            adminAddress("localhost:13046")
        }   
        sshdPort 17743       
        cordapp (project(':workflows'))
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
}
```

But on executing this deployNodes task we are getting the following error in member-info-gen.log file in the node directory:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...

Logs can be found in                    : C:\Corda_5.0\sample_app\cordapp\build\nodes\Notary\logs
[ERROR] 14:17:34+0530 [net.corda.node.OSGiNodeActivator.start] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Exception during node startup: Collection contains no element matching the predicate. {}
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$updateMemberInfo$memberInfoAndSigned$1.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:1423)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$updateMemberInfo$memberInfoAndSigned$1.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:259)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.MemberInfoAndSigned$Companion.create(SignedMemberInfo.kt:64)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.updateMemberInfo(AbstractNode.kt:941)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.generateAndSaveMemberInfo(AbstractNode.kt:727)
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.generateAndSaveMemberInfo(Node.kt:500)
    at net.corda.node.internal.subcommands.GenerateNodeInfoCli$runProgram$1.run(GenerateNodeInfoCli.kt:12)
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup$initialiseAndRun$9.invoke(NodeStartup.kt:228)
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup$initialiseAndRun$9.invoke(NodeStartup.kt:142)
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupLogging.attempt(NodeStartup.kt:608)
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.initialiseAndRun(NodeStartup.kt:217)
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.initialiseAndRun$default(NodeStartup.kt:158)
    at net.corda.node.internal.subcommands.GenerateNodeInfoCli.runProgram(GenerateNodeInfoCli.kt:10)
    at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase.call(CordaCliWrapper.kt:163)
    at net.corda.cliutils.CliWrapperBase.call(CordaCliWrapper.kt:126)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1933)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1200(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2332)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2326)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2291)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2159)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2058)
    at net.corda.cliutils.CordaCliWrapperKt.start(CordaCliWrapper.kt:114)
    at net.corda.node.OSGiNodeActivator$start$1.invoke(OSGiNodeActivator.kt:45)
    at net.corda.node.OSGiNodeActivator$start$1.invoke(OSGiNodeActivator.kt:19)
    at kotlin.concurrent.ThreadsKt$thread$thread$1.run(Thread.kt:30)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\cordauser\AppData\Local\Temp\osgi-cache14475741493334210436\cache.lock: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:274)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:105)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1142)
    at net.corda.osgi.framework.OSGiFrameworkMain$bootstrap$1$1.invoke(OSGiFrameworkMain.kt:157)
    at net.corda.osgi.framework.OSGiFrameworkMain$bootstrap$1$1.invoke(OSGiFrameworkMain.kt:20)
    at net.corda.osgi.framework.OSGiFrameworkMain$sam$java_util_function_Consumer$0.accept(OSGiFrameworkMain.kt)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at net.corda.osgi.framework.OSGiFrameworkMain$bootstrap$1.run(OSGiFrameworkMain.kt:157)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Shutting down ...
```

Has anybody used Cordformation plugin with Corda 5 developer release and faced similar problem? Or have any guesses as to whats wrong here?

On running the deployNodes task it creates the node folders but all nodes have the same error shown above in member-info-gen.log.

Comment: Corda 5 is a completely different software. If you are trying something that is not explicitly mentioned in the Corda 5 official documentation, do not waste your time trying to use Corda 4 plugins with it because they will all likely not work.

Comment: @AlessandroBaffa, I understand your point, but we are using the plugin version meant for Corda 5 only. As per Corda Gradle plugins [documentation](https://github.com/corda/corda-gradle-plugins) "Corda 5 requires Corda Gradle Plugins 6.x." and we are using "6.0.0-DevPreview" version which is supposed to work with Corda 5 Dev Preview version.